# Integrate Agora.io with Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, agora.io

I want to build a video chat application whose backend is going to be built with **node.js and socket.io** ... How to integrate **Agora.io** with node.js and socket.io.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora Web SDK can be used as a frontend library, the only server component required is to generate tokens for authentication.

You can use this [NodeJS project](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Node-TokenServer) to generate tokens.

Comment: thanks very much